# How can I print R documentation from a Linux command shell (e.g. bash)?

Tags: r

How can I check documentation for R code from a Linux command shell such as bash? I DO NOT mean an interactive session.

With Perl, I can use `perldoc` to print out documentation at the command line:

```
perldoc lib
```

I was hoping for something simple like that for R. I don't always want to pull up a full interactive R session just to look up some documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be other ways, but one that works for me is using the `-e` flag to execute code on the command line. I also use the `--slave` flag, which prevents anything from being printed to standard output (e.g. no R startup messages, etc.):

```
R --slave -e '?function'
```

I actually created a super small script I call `rdoc` to act like a simple R version of `perldoc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
R --slave -e "?$1"
```

After installing that in my `~/bin` directory (or however you install it in your `PATH`), it's easy:

```
rdoc function
```

If you want to look at documentation of a function from a particular package, prepend the library name followed by two colons. For example, to pull up documentation of the `dmrFinder` function from the `charm` package:

```
rdoc charm::dmrFinder
```